# how can I save as much memory as possible by compressing the texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script to download some images from the web on click page, and when I moved to the second page, a second set of images was downloaded, but the problem is that the image size is relatively large, and when there are more than one image, it consumes a lot of RAM, how can I save as much memory as possible by compressing the texture

this is my Code

```
IEnumerator D_Image(string url_)
{
    Destroy(Icon.texture);
    Icon.texture = LoadT;
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url_))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Icon.texture = ErrorT;
        }
        else
        {
            Icon.texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
        }
        uwr.Dispose();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try compressing the images, it makes a big difference
You can use this code
I found it in this [TextureOps](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityTextureOps) add-on

```
public static Texture2D Scale( Texture sourceTex, int targetWidth, int targetHeight, TextureFormat format = TextureFormat.RGBA32, Options options = new Options() )
  {
    if( sourceTex == null )
      throw new ArgumentException( "Parameter 'sourceTex' is null!" );

    Texture2D result = null;

    RenderTexture rt = RenderTexture.GetTemporary( targetWidth, targetHeight );
    RenderTexture activeRT = RenderTexture.active;

    try
    {
      Graphics.Blit( sourceTex, rt );
      RenderTexture.active = rt;

      result = new Texture2D( targetWidth, targetHeight, format, options.generateMipmaps, options.linearColorSpace );
      result.ReadPixels( new Rect( 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight ), 0, 0, false );
      result.Apply( options.generateMipmaps, options.markNonReadable );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
      Debug.LogException( e );

      Object.Destroy( result );
      result = null;
    }
    finally
    {
      RenderTexture.active = activeRT;
      RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary( rt );
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Actually I was trying to add it now and it worked great for me